# Data Safety Form - How can as a Developer know which Data third party SDK collects and sends off?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

My app was rejected on Google Play because I have invalid Data safety form and I did not disclose that my app collects and shares "Apps On Device". Frankly, **I did not know that it does** and I think this is the problem. Most SDK providers do not "cleanly" disclose what they are collecting.

Maybe I'm missing something BUT the SDK providers SHOULD disclose what they are collecting and what we should then disclose in Google and Apple Data Privacy Safety forms.
How can I as a DEVELOPER know what kind of data types the SDK that I use in my app collects and sends off the device?

So is there any way why Google thinks I'm sending this data off the device? How can I know which library accesses and sends this info off device?

I'm using:

1. Admob
2. GameAnalytics
3. Unity Ads (as a mediating package).

I could however, solve this rejection by disclosing that my app shares "installed apps" data, but I refuse to do so. I want to know exactly WHICH library does this and then decide if I want to remove it or keep it.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's hard to find exactly what's collected by a particular library. In your case probably the Analytics plugin is collecting installed apps data. See a Unity statement [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/Manual/UnityAnalyticsGoogleDataSafety.html).

In my Unity games I have disabled all analytics related plugins and so far I have no issues with the safety form.

As for Admob, finally you can easily find official Data Safety form statements at Google sites.

Also, the community have created a registry containing popular libraries with collected data information: [SDK Privacy Report](https://github.com/Privado-Inc/SDK-Privacy-Report)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer was helpful, but it seems this is for Unity LEGACY Analytics. As I understand legacy Analytics is Analytics enabled via SERVICES window. I already set this to OFF and is not active in this particular package. Can there be any "leftovers" of this library even if turned off? Additionally the case is even more bizzare because I published this package in end of July and it went through easily 2 times (changing metadata only) but the 3rd time was rejected. Before that my app wasn't collect the mentioned data?

Comment: I'm not up to date with Unity, but in my notes I can see that I disabled both Analyctics and InApp Purchasing (it was enabled by default and it also uses Analytics under the hood) packages from Package Manager. And also I removed `"com.unity.modules.unityanalytics": "1.0.0"` entry from `manifest.json` and `package.lock`, because it was still added there.